# How can I set a url that takes one parameter with aphanumeric string?

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

What I'm trying to do:

```
url(r'^confirmemail/[a-bA-z0-9]+/', 'blog.views.confirmemail'),
```

The exact url would be something like that: http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirmemail/tubwp2n0a6 or http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirmemail/tubwp2n0a6/

The length of the string parameter would be ten(10).

How can  write that url in urls.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`url(r'^confirmemail/(?P<code>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', 'blog.views.confirmemail'),`

or

`url(r'^confirmemail/(?P<code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/', 'blog.views.confirmemail'),` to restrict length to the 10 symbols.

Comment: What is `?P<code>`? Is there any difference between putting a ending slash or not putting a ending slash? like: `url(r'^confirmemail/(?P<code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/', 'blog.views.confirmemail'),` or `url(r'^confirmemail/(?P<code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})', 'blog.views.confirmemail'),`

Comment: `(?P<code>...)` say Django to catch a part of the url and pass it to the view as named argument with name `code`.Usually it is ok to omit ending slash, if you don't want it.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
url(r'^confirmemail/[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}/', 'blog.views.confirmemail')
```

**Edit**: Please see Alexander Artemenko's answer for a fuller solution.

Comment: I think you have to use the capturing expressions around the regex in Django (don't have it setup so I can't test right now). If you want it a little shorter (and with capturing expression) you could us the character classes: url(r'^confirmemail/([\w\d]{10})/', 'blog.views.confirmemail')

Comment: Is there any difference between putting a ending slash or not putting a ending slash? like: `url(r'^confirmemail/[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}/', 'blog.views.confirmemail')
` or `url(r'^confirmemail/[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}/', 'blog.views.confirmemail')`

Comment: You made mistake, it should be `url(r'^confirmemail/([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})/$', 'blog.views.confirmemail')

Comment: @guru: The `$` isn't required, though it's useful to ensure that trailing junk isn't caught.

Comment: @guru: Ah, yes, you're right. They're not in the original question, and I didn't have the insight to see that they'd be useful here.